# how to find a share printer on LAN?

Tags: printer

I just want to know how to discover a network printer IP address on LAN network or a share printer of someone else. 
Can I use nmap to discover network printer ? 
my network printer is HP laserjet 1320

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an HP jetdirect-style printer, you can try to scan the network for it...

```
nmap -sT -p 9100 192.168.0.1-254
```

Would return the scan of devices on the 192.168.0.0 network, showing those with port 9100 open.